# How to add a git sub-module to a super-project in code using libgit2

Tags: git, installation, addition, git-submodules, libgit2

I have successfully created two git repositories (named repo and module) in code using the libgit2 C API and am now trying to add the "module" repository to the "repo" repository as a submodule. I am trying to use the libgit2 git_submodule_add_setup C API to do this. See https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/submodule/git_submodule_add_setup.

The documentation says the following:

git_submodule_add_setup:
This does "git submodule add" up to the fetch and checkout of the submodule contents. It preps a new submodule, creates an entry in .gitmodules and creates an empty initialized repository either at the given path in the working directory or in .git/modules with a gitlink from the working directory to the new repo.

**To fully emulate "git submodule add" call this function, then open the submodule repo and perform the clone step as needed**. Lastly, call git_submodule_add_finalize() to wrap up adding the new submodule and .gitmodules to the index to be ready to commit.

My question is how exactly do I perform the clone operation alluded to above given that the call to git_submodule_add_setup creates a initialised, but empty submodule (with a .git directory inside it)? I have already made several attempts to do the clone using the git_submodule_open and git_clone C APIs, but to no avail. The clone fails because the submodule is not an empty folder. I have read the git_clone C API documentation at and have also familiarised myself with the example code at https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/101-samples/#repositories_clone_simple etc., but I am still none the wiser. Some help from those in the the know would be much appreciated.

I have included a code snippet below to give a flavour of what I have so far.

```
namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;
git_repository * repo = NULL;
bfs::path const repo_path = bfs::current_path() / "repo";
std::string const repo_url = repo_path.string();
git_repository_init(&repo, repo_url.c_str(), 0);

//Add various files to repo index, and commit them...

git_repository * module = NULL;
bfs::path const module_path = bfs::current_path() / "module";
std::string const module_url = module_path.string();
git_repository_init(&module, module_url.c_str(), 0);

//Add various files to moduleindex, and commit them...

git_submodule * submodule = NULL;
git_submodule_add_setup(&submodule, repo, module_url.c_str(), "module", 0);

//What do I need to do in here to clone the module into position??

git_submodule_add_finalize(submodule);
git_submodule_free(submodule);

git_repository_free(module);
git_repository_free(repo);
```

Comment: I need the answer badly ;(

Answer (score 3):

I've had my problems with adding submodules as well.
Here is my [Github issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/4149).

Fortunately, a contributer gave me this working example.

```
#include <git2.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int just_return_origin(git_remote **out, git_repository *repo, const char *name, const char *url, void *payload)
{
    return git_remote_lookup(out, repo, name);
}

static int just_return_repo(git_repository **out, const char *path, int bare, void *payload)
{
    git_submodule *sm = payload;
    return git_submodule_open(out, sm);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    git_clone_options opts = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
    git_submodule *sm;
    git_repository *parent, *child;
    int result = 0;

    git_libgit2_init();

    result = git_repository_open(&parent, "parent");
    assert(!result);

    assert(!git_submodule_add_setup(&sm, parent, "file:///tmp/sm/child", "sm_test", 1));

    opts.repository_cb = just_return_repo;
    opts.repository_cb_payload = sm;
    opts.remote_cb = just_return_origin;
    opts.remote_cb_payload = sm;

    assert(!git_clone(&child, "file:///tmp/sm/child", "sm_test", &opts));
    assert(!git_submodule_add_finalize(sm));

    git_submodule_free(sm);
    git_repository_free(child);
    git_repository_free(parent);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe this example helps you as well (even though this question is rather old).