# How to add git sub-module in a repo using LibGit2sharp

Tags: c#, git, git-submodules, libgit2sharp

I'm working with a local Git repository in some .NET code using the open source library used by the Visual Studio Tools for Git, LibGit2Sharp.

I need to create some submodules. The code I used was:

```
$ git submodule add <remote_url> <destination_folder> 
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

Which I've obtained a new file called '.gitmodules' where says:

```
[submodule "destination_folder"]
    path = destination_folder
    url = http://<my_gitlab_domain>/projects/<my_project>/<submodule_name>.git
```

This works perfectly but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I've been looking up a way to get the same result by using the LibGit2Sharp API. I've been searching for any other similar posts, but they don't seem to be what I exactly need.

I saw this question about the same issue but in C++, but I don't find a way to make it work for C#.

[How to add a git sub-module to a super-project in code using libgit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122130/how-to-add-a-git-sub-module-to-a-super-project-in-code-using-libgit)

If any of you can help me by sending any source of information or an example for what I need I'll be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the libraries documentation? There might be some function to add a new submodule.

Comment: Yes, I looked if there were any implemented functions, but I didn't find anything about adding submodules.